# How to add one row for every page

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, visual-studio-2015, printing

I am using SQL Server, Visual Studio and C#. I have a table with some columns. From my .net page, I'm using a Grid View to show my data. The table will consist of about 400+ records at any given time. I'm trying click a button that will print out all the records in my table with one click but I need 1 record per page to print out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a controller action called PrintPage(pageNumber) that returns a FileResult. The file result will be what you would like to print. In that method do a Skip() and a Take() on your result data set to limit it to the requested page.